# Pass object properties by reference with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a polymer `<parent-element>` that contains a large JS object.

Within this `<parent-element>`, I have N `<child-element>` that both consume the large JS object.

If I pass the large JS object to the `<child-element>` as a property it will create a "deep" copy.

```
// in <parent-element>
<div>
  <child-element id="child1" largeobject="{{largeobject}}"></child-element>
  <child-element id="child2" largeobject="{{largeobject}}"></child-element>
  //...
</div>
```

Which would be the best practice to pass an element by reference?

Just attach it to the `<child-element>` programmatically?

```
// in <parent-element>
ready: function(){
  this.$.child1.largeobject = this.largeobject;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it passes a reference. Why do you think it creates a deep copy?

Comment: hmm because they recommend to use this.set, this.push, etc. to modify things. Also maybe the only reason for using this.set or this.push, etc. is to notify other elements to update the view.
I'll put a jsbin together to test it

Comment: The notifications are exactly the reasons for this API. This way Polymer doesn't need to compare values repeatedly to check for possible changes and gains a lot of performance.

Comment: You are right, all is happening by reference it seems

Comment: https://jsbin.com/fozotu/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is already happening by reference with the syntax:

```
// in <parent-element>
<div>
  <child-element id="child1" largeobject="{{largeobject}}"></child-element>
  <child-element id="child2" largeobject="{{largeobject}}"></child-element>
  //...
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/fozotu/edit?html,console,output